# Query to split data from rows into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like this in SQL Server:

| Client Name | Client ID Type | Client ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John Dee | Netflix ID | 2563 |
| John Dee | Facebook ID | 546543 |
| Sara Spence | Netflix ID | 7985 |
| Sara Spence | Facebook ID | 568867 |
| Mark Brown | Netflix ID | 8635 |
| Mark Brown | Facebook ID | 597489 |

I want to make query and show the data from row into column, expecting the result like this:

| Client Name | Netflix ID | Facebook ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John Dee | 2563 | 546543 |
| Sara Spence | 7985 | 568867 |
| Mark Brown | 8635 | 597489 |

Is there any solution to show the table from row into column? I have many data in the table.

Version

> Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU15) (KB5008996) - 15.0.4198.2 (X64)   Jan 12 2022 22:30:08   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
> Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: You need to do your research, have a go, and post your attempt when stuck rather than asking us to solve the entire problem for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

It follows the same **minimal reproducible example** paradigm. It is copied to SSMS as-is, executed, and you are getting the desired output.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ClientName VARCHAR(20), ClientIDType VARCHAR(20), ClientID INT);
INSERT @tbl (ClientName, ClientIDType, ClientID) VALUES
('John Dee', 'Netflix ID', 2563),
('John Dee', 'Facebook ID', 546543),
('Sara Spence', 'Netflix ID',   7985),
('Sara Spence', 'Facebook ID',  568867),
('Mark Brown', 'Netflix ID',    8635),
('Mark Brown', 'Facebook ID', 597489);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT ClientName, [Netflix ID] AS NetflixID, [Facebook ID] AS FacebookID
FROM 
   ( SELECT ClientName, ClientIDType, ClientID
     FROM @tbl 
   ) ps
PIVOT
   ( SUM (ClientID)
     FOR ClientIDType IN ( [Netflix ID], [Facebook ID])
   ) AS pvt;
```

**Output**

| ClientName | NetflixID | FacebookID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John Dee | 2563 | 546543 |
| Mark Brown | 8635 | 597489 |
| Sara Spence | 7985 | 568867 |

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server provides a PIVOT and UNPIVOT feature that should do what you are looking for.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Suitable as a tip in a comment but its not a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just a JOIN would do in this case:

```sql
SELECT 
    t1.ClientName,
    t1.ClientID as NetflixID,
    t2.ClientID as FacebookID
FROM tbl t1
INNER JOIN tbl t2 on t1.ClientName=t2.ClientName and t2.ClientIDType='Facebook ID'
WHERE t1.ClientIdType='Netflix ID'
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/5H-CHocD)

or one could just group by ClientName:

```sql
select 
    ClientName, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN ClientIDType='Netflix ID' THEN ClientID END) as 'Netflix ID',
    SUM(CASE WHEN ClientIDType='Facebook ID' THEN ClientID END) as 'Facebook ID'
FROM tbl
GROUP BY ClientName;
```